# Nservicebus4 installation

Tags: installation, nservicebus, windows-server-2003

I encountered with a problem when i installed the `particular-nservicebus-4.0.2.exe` on the `Windows Server 2003 SP2(32bit,64bit)`. The error is:

```
A file that is required cannot be installed because the cabinet file C\document and settings\Administrator Data\Particular software Ltd\NServiceBus4.0.2\install\disk1.cab has an invalid digital signature. this may indicate the cabinet file is corrupt
```

But it is ok when i installed it on the `windows server 2008R2`, it seems that `server 2003` and `xp` cannot support it.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may see this message when installing under Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, typically with a cabinet file greater than 500MB. To correct this problem, install the following Windows update:

For Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960554/en-us

For Windows Server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888303/en-us